# I can't delete photos on my iPhone 4s even though the delete button is there, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I've selected the photos I want to delete but, the delete button isn't turning blue. They were all taken on the iPhone but, the sim card has been removed. Do I need the sim card or not to delete the images?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are these photos that were taken on this iPhone or  were synced from your computer?

Comment: If you sync-ed the pictures via your Mac/PC you can only delete them by deleting them on your computer not on the phone. Then when you sync the photos will then be deleted.

Comment: Do use iCloud Photos?

Comment: fsb, they were taken on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

SIM presence changes nothing. Even if you have iCloud photos you can delete photos without service or network and then those changes will only sync up once you connect.

Something else is amiss. Do you have a backup of the device and opportunity to test a restart / reset / restore?